# Size Math font – Define different sizes for Display and Text Equations globally

Tags: math-mode, equations, fontsize

I have a rather long document with plenty of maths and equations. As the equations are quite long I have chosen to use 8pt for equations in the display mode instead of the 10pt normal size.

`\DeclareMathSizes{10}{8}{6}{6}` globally changes all equations in math mode to 8pt font.

Is there a way to stick with 10pt in textstyle equations?, i.e. is it possible to differentiate between displaystyle and textstyle?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) We typically do not include greetings but use upvoting of answers as a "Thanks".

Comment: i think you mean "display and text environments"; "displaystyle" can be used (for example) to get a "full size" fraction in text, and vice versa.  i'd take a look at `\everydisplay` for a means of determining the context.

Comment: Barbara, you are right. Is there a way to add a specific definition of sizes to \everydisplay? scriptstyle is to small whereas the normal style is to large.... is there a way to define sizes of a formula locally?

Comment: since i'm not intimately familiar with these inner workings, i will take some digging.  that's why i just left a suggestion.  if no one else comes forward, i'll dig when i have some time.

Comment: May be I should formulate the question in another way: How can specific sizes for normal math text, superscripts, subscripts etc... be chosen for only single equations?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear exactly what your question is but you ask in comments of it is possible to locally affect the size of formulae. The standard LaTeX font commands affect math as well as text so you can do this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

xxx $a=b$ yyy

zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
\[a=b\]
yy yy yy yy yy yy yy yy 

zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
{\small\[a=b\]}%
yy yy yy yy yy yy yy yy 

\end{document}
```